# Reduce font size of title in template article

Tags: titles

I want reduce font size of title in template article. the template is http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wenneker-article

When I modify the size of the title, it affects the title of all the pages, how do I do it so that it only affects the main title?

it would also be useful, remove the title of the other pages

**the first page is perfect**
[image]

**But so you see the second page**

[image]

Comment: `article` is a standard template. There is no need to include the template in this case. To do what you want, just type `\title{\small Title}` in the preamble.

Comment: @YiFan 
I would like to put a size manually, 14 or 15

Comment: That's easy too: check the `anyfontsize` package.

Comment: @YiFan 
When I modify the size of the title, it affects the title of all the pages, how do I do it so that it only affects the main title?

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example (MWE) which reproduces your problem so that I and others can see the issue. As I described there should be no issue. Make sure that you add braces before the font size command and after the text you want to change the size of.

Comment: @YiFan 
I do not know how to just give an example, I'm new with latex is quite confusing, edit my question

Comment: Try looking at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 to get a sense of MWEs. It's difficult for me to give you suggestions without actually seeing your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is essentially the file `structure.tex`, where we read

```
\pretitle{
        \vspace{-30pt} % Move the entire title section up
        \HorRule\vspace{10pt} % Horizontal rule before the title
        \fontsize{32}{36}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\selectfont % Helvetica
        \color{DarkRed} % Text colour for the title and author(s)
}
```

Just change `\fontsize{32}{36}` to the combination of size and baseline skip you prefer.

You can avoid modifying `structure.tex`; just issue in your preamble something like

```
\pretitle{%
        \vspace{-30pt}% Move the entire title section up
        \HorRule\vspace{10pt}% Horizontal rule before the title
        \fontsize{18}{24}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\selectfont % Helvetica
        \color{DarkRed}% Text colour for the title and author(s)
}
```

to which you can make other adjustments according to your likings.

In order to cope with the very long title, you can provide a shorter version to be set in the header by adding

```
\chead{Short title}
```

before `\begin{document}`

Comment: I try it and it does not solve the problem of the second image.

Comment: @x-rw Well, such a long title cannot fit the header, can it?

Comment: yes exactly, the font is big i want reduce o delete that title

Comment: @x-rw The font for the header is the standard one, unless you have size instructions inside `\title`, which you shouldn't. I added how to print a shorter version of the title.